# Как составить регулярное выражение, чтобы в строке в начале был плюс, а далее только цифры?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Как составить регулярное выражение для подобных строк (+ и цифры)?

```
+79990215487
+74212125459
+38021548782545
+1124587
```

Регулярное выражение для номера телефона, но не под какую-то конкретную страну, поэтому количество символов произвольное.

Comment: У меня такое выражение пропускает и текст с плюсом в начале

Comment: ^\+\d+$ - добавил знаки окончания и начала строки

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как-то так, если надо целые строки:

```
/^\+\d+$/
```